# Zoomed out d3 map from mapshaper.org

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, mapshaper

Can someone pls tell me what i'm doing wrong. I exported a topojson from mapshaper.org. Then I drew the map using the d3. But the map appears zoomed out(very small). How do I get it to be properly scaled and centered. Pls note that i've used some solutions on stackoverflow and I've tried fitExtent. The issue with fitExtent is that I will not be able to translate the map later when I need to. I want the loaded map to appear scaled and centered. Here's the code to draw the map

```
   let width = 900
   let height = 500
   let svg = null
   let chartContainer = null

   // load data
   let map = {}    
   const inputFilepath3 =  '../Data/nigeria.topojson' 
   const data =  await d3.json(inputFilepath3)
   const object = data.objects.gadm36_NGA_1
   map.features = topojson.feature(data, object).features

 // build container
           if (!svg) {
                svg = d3.select('body')
                        .append('svg')
                chartContainer = svg.append('g')
                                    .classed('chart-container', true) 
            }[![enter image description here][1]][1]

            svg.attr('width', width)
            svg.attr('height', height)
            // build scale
            const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

            // build geopath generator
            const projection = d3.geoAzimuthalEqualArea() 
            const geoPath = d3.geoPath(null).projection(projection)

            // draw map
            let ps = chartContainer.selectAll('path.state').data(map.features)
            ps.exit().remove()
            ps.enter().append('path').classed('state', true)
                       .attr('d', geoPath)
                       .attr('fill', function(d,i) {
                           return colorScale(i)
                       })
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: You can apply a translate with fixExtent - fitExtenet sets the translate, but there is nothing stopping you from modifying it afterwards, for example, by translating further, or translating with a zoom/drag function outside the projection altogether.